# Not getting publish message from pubnub but showing on pubnub history response

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, pubnub

**Not getting publish message from pubnub but showing on pubnub history response.**

**Case:**
After below mentioned publish response, not getting publish message from device end.But device message showing on pubnub history response.

```
{
  :code=>200, 
  :operation=>:publish, 
  :client_request=>#<URI::HTTP http://pubsub.pubnub.com/publish/pub-c-****-37d32e2a1d43/sub-c-***-0619f8945a4f/0/broadcast_57c05de753545020a5000000/0/%7B%22channelType%22%3A%222%22%2C%22PublisherId%22%3A%22577e0cfc69702d11fb010000%22%2C%22listener_count%22%3A%225%22%2C%22totalLikeCount%22%3A%220%22%2C%22chat_id%22%3A%2257c05fe5535450232b040000%22%2C%22created_at%22%3A%222016-08-26T15%3A27%3A33.548Z%22%2C%22pubnub_timestamp%22%3Anull%2C%22text%22%3A%22samar_us7%40yopmail.com%20has%20join%20broadcast.%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22JoinUser%22%2C%22user%22%3A%7B%22bio%22%3Anull%2C%22country%22%3A%22US%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22samar_us7%40yopmail.com%22%2C%22initial_sync_done%22%3Atrue%2C%22is_syncing%22%3Afalse%2C%22two_years_sync_done%22%3Atrue%2C%22account_type%22%3A%22SPTProductUnknown%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22samar_us7%40yopmail.com%22%2C%22platform_id%22%3A%22samar_us7%22%2C%22platform_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fopen.spotify.com%2Fuser%2Fsamar_us7%22%2C%22user_id%22%3A%22577e0cfc69702d11fb010000%22%2C%22listeners_count%22%3A2%2C%22lyric%22%3A%22Rebirth%20of%20Cool%22%2C%22profile_picture_url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.64%3A3000%2Fassets%2Fuser_profile_small_cover_image.png%22%2C%22likes%22%3A0%2C%22followers%22%3A2%2C%22following%22%3A0%2C%22broadcasts%22%3A104%2C%22broadcast_listeners_count%22%3A343%7D%7D?pnsdk=PubNub-Ruby/4.0.7&uuid=d966d2a7-5d7e-4fac-8158-1b9a15226165&seqn=6&ortt=%7B%22t%22%3A14722252542914316%7D>, 
  :server_response=>#<HTTP::Message:0x000000044fa1d8 @http_header=#<HTTP::Message::Headers:0x000000044fa160 @http_version="1.1", @body_size=0, @chunked=false, @request_method="GET", @request_uri=#<Addressable::URI:0x227d7b8 URI:http://pubsub.pubnub.com/publish/pub-c-***-37d32e2a1d43/sub-c-***-0619f8945a4f/0/broadcast_57c05de753545020a5000000/0/%7B%22channelType%22%3A%222%22%2C%22PublisherId%22%3A%22577e0cfc69702d11fb010000%22%2C%22listener_count%22%3A%225%22%2C%22totalLikeCount%22%3A%220%22%2C%22chat_id%22%3A%2257c05fe5535450232b040000%22%2C%22created_at%22%3A%222016-08-26T15%3A27%3A33.548Z%22%2C%22pubnub_timestamp%22%3Anull%2C%22text%22%3A%22samar_us7%40yopmail.com%20has%20join%20broadcast.%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22JoinUser%22%2C%22user%22%3A%7B%22bio%22%3Anull%2C%22country%22%3A%22US%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22samar_us7%40yopmail.com%22%2C%22initial_sync_done%22%3Atrue%2C%22is_syncing%22%3Afalse%2C%22two_years_sync_done%22%3Atrue%2C%22account_type%22%3A%22SPTProductUnknown%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22samar_us7%40yopmail.com%22%2C%22platform_id%22%3A%22samar_us7%22%2C%22platform_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fopen.spotify.com%2Fuser%2Fsamar_us7%22%2C%22user_id%22%3A%22577e0cfc69702d11fb010000%22%2C%22listeners_count%22%3A2%2C%22lyric%22%3A%22Rebirth%20of%20Cool%22%2C%22profile_picture_url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.64%3A3000%2Fassets%2Fuser_profile_small_cover_image.png%22%2C%22likes%22%3A0%2C%22followers%22%3A2%2C%22following%22%3A0%2C%22broadcasts%22%3A104%2C%22broadcast_listeners_count%22%3A343%7D%7D?pnsdk=PubNub-Ruby/4.0.7&uuid=d966d2a7-5d7e-4fac-8158-1b9a15226165&seqn=5&ortt=%7B%22t%22%3A14722252541270930%7D>, @request_query=nil, @request_absolute_uri=nil, @status_code=200, @reason_phrase="OK", @body_type=nil, @body_charset=nil, @body_date=nil, @body_encoding=#<Encoding:UTF-8>, @is_request=false, @header_item=[["Date", "Fri, 26 Aug 2016 15:27:33 GMT"], ["Content-Type", "text/javascript; charset=\"UTF-8\""], ["Content-Length", "30"], ["Connection", "keep-alive"], ["Cache-Control", "no-cache"], ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"], ["Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET"]], @dumped=false>, @peer_cert=nil, @http_body=#<HTTP::Message::Body:0x000000044f9f08 @body="[1,\"Sent\",\"14722252530221972\"]", @size=0, @positions=nil, @chunk_size=nil>, @previous=nil>, 
  :data=>nil,
  :category=>:ack, 
  :error=>false, 
  :auto_retried=>false, 
  :current_timetoken=>nil, 
  :last_timetoken=>nil, 
  :subscribed_channels=>nil, 
  :subscribed_channel_groups=>nil, 
  :config=>{
    :tls=>false, 
    :uuid=>"d966d2a7-5d7e-4fac-8158-1b9a15226165", 
    :auth_key=>nil,
    :origin=>"pubsub.pubnub.com"
  }
}
```

IOS code:

Publish Code:

```
[ApplicationDelegate.client publish:publishChatDictionary toChannel:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"broadcast_%@",[BroadcastManager sharedInstance].broadcast.identifier] withCompletion:^(PNPublishStatus * _Nonnull status) {
           if (!status.isError) {
               chat.pubNubTimeStamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)[status.data.timetoken integerValue]];
               // Message successfully published to specified channel.
           }else {
               // because of which request did fail.
               // Request can be resent using:
                [status retry];
           }
       }];
```

// Subsriber code:

```
[ApplicationDelegate.client addListener:(id)self];
 //  [ApplicationDelegate.client.currentConfiguration setUUID:[UserManager sharedInstance].user.identifier];
   [ApplicationDelegate.client subscribeToChannels: @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"broadcastLikes_%@",[BroadcastManager sharedInstance].broadcast.identifier], [NSString stringWithFormat:@"broadcast_%@",[BroadcastManager sharedInstance].broadcast.identifier]] withPresence:YES];

//Callback method:

- (void)client:(PubNub *)client didReceiveMessage:(PNMessageResult *)message {

   // Handle new message stored in message.data.message
   if (message.data.actualChannel) {

       // Message has been received on channel group stored in
       // message.data.subscribedChannel
   }
   else {

       // Message has been received on channel stored in
       // message.data.subscribedChannel
   }
}
```

I have ruby code where I have added presence callback, I want to know , is anything wrong there in code.Please check below and let me know.

Subscriber callback:

```
 def callbacks
    callbacks = Pubnub::SubscribeCallback.new(
    message:  ->(envelope) { 
      # puts "#{envelope.result[:data]}"
      subscription_callback(envelope.result)
    },
    presence: ->(envelope) { 
      # puts #{envelope.result[:data][:message]}"
      presence_callback(envelope.result) 
    },
    status:   ->(envelope) do
      if envelope.status[:error]
        case envelope.status[:category]
          when Pubnub::Constants::STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED # :access_denied
            puts "Access Denied"
          when Pubnub::Constants::STATUS_TIMEOUT # :timeout
            puts "Timeout error"
          when Pubnub::Constants::STATUS_NON_JSON_RESPONSE # :non_json_response
            puts "Non json response"
          when Pubnub::Constants::STATUS_API_KEY_ERROR # :api_key_error
            puts "API key error"
          when Pubnub::Constants::STATUS_ERROR
            puts "Other Pubnub error"
          else
            puts "Something went wrong"
          end
        end
      end 
    ) 
  end 

Presence Callback:

  def presence_callback(result)
    Pubnub.logger.info("==============================================================presence_callback") 
    Pubnub.logger.info(result.to_json) 
    broadcast_id = result[:channel].split("_")[1] rescue result[:data][:subscribed_channel].split("-")[0].split("-")[1]
    broadcast = Broadcast.find(broadcast_id)
    if broadcast.is_fake_broadcast
      track = Track.with_platform_id(broadcast.current_track_id, "Spotify").first
      Pubnub.logger.info("============================================================== channel : #{channel}, state : #{state}, uuid : #{uuid}") 
      Pubnub.logger.info(result.to_json)
      state = { "is_live" =>   broadcast.is_live, "listener_count" =>  broadcast.broadcast_listener_ids.count.to_s, "likeIcons" =>  broadcast.fetch_used_like_images, "totalLikeCount" =>  broadcast.get_broadcast_likes_count, "is_track_change" =>  false, "track" =>  track.as_json, "track_count" =>  broadcast.tracks.count, "track_position" =>  broadcast.set_track_position}
      if result[:action] == 'join'      
        $pubnub.set_state(channel: result[:channel], state: state) do |envelope|
          puts envelope.result[:data][:state]
        end
      elsif result[:action] == 'leave'
        $pubnub.set_state(channel: result[:channel], state: state) do |envelope|
          puts envelope.result[:data][:state]
        end
      end
    end            
  end
```

Comment: Can you share code which is used on iOS side to subscribe and listen for messages (make sure to exclude publish / subscribe keys from your response)?

Comment: Let us know if you can provide code as *Serhii* requested.

Comment: @SerhiiMamontov I have added IOS code above you can check there and let me know if something is missing.

Comment: @ManishNagdewani I see what for subscribe on iOS device you use name channel name template prefixed with `broadcastLikes_` but **Ruby** SDK used to publish method to channel which prefixed with `broadcast_`. Please, make sure what names of channel on which iOS subscribed is the same as used during publish on another platforms (like **Ruby**).

Comment: @SerhiiMamontov, As you can see above code, iOS has also subscribed channel name template prefixed with broadcast_ and broadcastLikes_.

Comment: @ManishNagdewani my bad, didn't scrolled to the end of code snippet. Can you enable logging like this `[PNLog enabled:YES];` before PubNub client usage and make sure what channel `broadcast_57c05de753545020a5000000` will appear in resulting log for `subscribe` request? Also make sure what **Objective-C** client configured with same publish and subscribe keys as **Ruby** client. Aside it looks good. How you verify what method not called, did you placed breakpoint? Try add logs into callback method to output any string.

Comment: @SerhiiMamontov I have ruby code where I have added presence callback, I want to know , is anything wrong there in code.Am I fetching result is right way?Please check above and let me know.

Comment: @SerhiiMamontov Also can you tell me correct syntax for set state and get state in ruby?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. All started as question about why message published from **Ruby** doesn't reach **iOS** client - I suggested to check here whether both **Ruby** and **iOS** use correct channels for subscription (on **iOS** side) and publish (on **Ruby** side). I don't see why presence callback appeared here, because you won't see any messages arrival with it. As for **Ruby** client I will ask @CraigConover to suggest further direction (maybe it will be better to contact support@pubnub.com if he will suggest).

Comment: Yes, please submit full issue details to [PubNub Support](https://pubnub.com/support) and include a link to this SO thread.